# Should I check to see if document.getElementById is defined

Tags: javascript

I ran across some webpage javascript code which first checks for the existence of `document.getElementById` itself before the more expected check of a particular element:

```
if (document.getElementById) {
    var elem = document.getElementById("someid");
    if (elem) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Is this a reasonable practice or hyper-paranoia?  And if reasonable, why not:

```
if (document && document.getElementById) { ... }
```

Comment: I'd check the "Sell By" date on that code. It hasn't been necessary to do that for a very long time, though various antique tutorials may still contain stuff like that.

Comment: hyper-paranoia, since the only browsers which wouldn't have gEBI() these days are so obsolete it's pointless to try and support them at all. it'd be like asking Fred Flintstone why his car doesn't have airbags or GPS...

Comment: if (document && document.getElementById) { ... } this is weird and unnecessary.
if (elem) this is good

Comment: Short answer - if you think dealing with IE 6 or 7 is bad, be glad you never had to work with IE 5. `document.getElementById` showed up in 5.5.

Comment: @degr "Weird", yes. But if this *was* running on a very old browser, `if elem()` wouldn't be sufficient - the script would crash on the call to (non-existent) `getElementById()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every modern browser has this function implemented. My guess is just that you were looking at some very old JavaScript code from an era when this wasn't the case.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById Contains a table with compatibility information on the function.

You don't need to check for document, or any of its more widely used functions in your code!

Comment: "*any* of its functions"? I wouldn't assume, for example, `document.querySelector()` if there's a chance you'll run into IE7 or Opera 9.

Comment: @PaulRoub, fair point. I updated my answer. I was trying to convey that for the most part checking for document functions is *generally* not needed but you're right in some cases it's mandated.

Answer (score 3):

[caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com) is a very helpful website for this kind of things. In this case, they say it is supported 'in all major browsers' and is 'safe to use'. They provide [a source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById#Browser_Compatibility), where you can find it is supported from:

- Chrome 1.0
- Firefox (Gecko) 1.0 (1.7 or earlier)
- IE 5.5
- Opera 7.0
- Safari (Webkit) 1.0
- Android 1.0
- Firefox (Mobile Gecko) 1.0 (1.0)
- IE Phone 6.0
- Opera Mobile 6.0
- Safari Mobile 1.0

Answer (score 2):

It's basic feature detection. The downside with this code is there is no graceful degradation. It should do something like:

```
if (feature) {
    // Use it
} else {
    // Graceful alternative
}
```

That being said, `getElementById` is widely available so this is antique code to me.